# How to FULL OUTER JOIN multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join, query-performance

I need to **`FULL OUTER JOIN`** multiple tables. I know how to `FULL OUTER JOIN` two tables from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql). But I have several tables, and I can't apply it over them. How can I achieve it?
My **SQL** code, below:

```
INSERT INTO table
(
  customer_id
 ,g01
 ,g02
 ,g03
 ,has_card
 ,activity
  )
  SELECT sgd.customer_id, sgd.g01,sgd.g02,sgd.g03,sc.value, a.activity
  FROM s_geo_data sgd
  LEFT JOIN s_category sc
  ON sc.customer_id = sgd.customer_id
    UNION
  SELECT sgd.customer_id, sgd.g01,sgd.g02,sgd.g03,sc.value, a.activity
  FROM s_geo_data sgd
  RIGHT JOIN s_category sc
  ON sc.customer_id = sgd.customer_id

    UNION

  SELECT sgd.customer_id, sgd.g01,sgd.g02,sgd.g03,sc.value, a.activity
  FROM s_geo_data sgd
  LEFT JOIN s_activity a
  ON a.customer_id = sgd.customer_id
    UNION
  SELECT sgd.customer_id, sgd.g01,sgd.g02,sgd.g03,sc.value, a.activity
  FROM s_geo_data sgd
  RIGHT JOIN s_activity a
  ON a.customer_id = sgd.customer_id
```

Also I tried this query:

```
INSERT INTO reportls.table
(
  customer_id
 ,g01
 ,g02
 ,g03
 ,has_card
 ,activity
  )
  SELECT sgd.customer_id, sgd.g01,sgd.g02,sgd.g03,sc.value, a.activity
  FROM s_geo_data sgd
  LEFT JOIN s_category sc
  ON sc.customer_id = sgd.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN s_activity a
  ON sc.customer_id = sgd.customer_id

    UNION

  SELECT sgd.customer_id, sgd.g01,sgd.g02,sgd.g03,sc.value, a.activity
  FROM s_geo_data sgd
  LEFT JOIN s_category sc
  ON sc.customer_id = sgd.customer_id
  RIGHT JOIN s_activity a
  ON a.customer_id = sgd.customer_id

    UNION

  SELECT sgd.customer_id, sgd.g01,sgd.g02,sgd.g03,sc.value, a.activity
  FROM s_geo_data sgd
  RIGHT JOIN s_category sc
  ON sc.customer_id = sgd.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN s_activity a
  ON a.customer_id = sgd.customer_id
```

Last query executes very long time, I need faster query.

Answer (score 2):

I think to have a `FULL OUTER JOIN` over 3 tables, you need to do it like this:

```
SELECT t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.value = t2.value
        LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.value = t3.value
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.value = t2.value
        LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.value = t3.value
WHERE t1.value IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
FROM t3 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.value = t3.value
        LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.value = t3.value
WHERE t1.value IS NULL AND t2.value IS NULL
```

As an alternative for this:

```
SELECT t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.value = t2.value
        FULL OUTER JOIN t3 ON t1.value = t3.value
```

---

I suggest you to create some temporary tables like `t1`, `t2` and `t3` for storing results of your queries, then use above query over those.

Comment: I execute your query, wait over 20 minutes, and pressed cancel. ))

Comment: Why you write **UNION ALL** not **UNION**?

Comment: @ШыназАлиш read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30497590/4519059), And `UNION ALL` is faster ;).

Comment: Does each table have an index (or `PRIMARY KEY`) on `(value)`?  That is vital to performance.  (In your case, `customer_id`.)

Comment: How does this scale for FULL OUTER JOINing `n` tables?

Comment: If you create temporary tables this will work only for the current session. Also the temporary tables will have the data at some specific time moment and will not be updated if the original tables changes meanwhile, your outer joins will not take into account the updated values from the original tables.