# Fill GataGridView by multi tables in Mysql c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I want to display data in a `DataGridView` control, this data will take its values from 3 tables `(boq_table, submittal, summary)` such as;

---

- `itemNum` || `descriptionOfWork` || `unit` || `contractualQuantity` || `priceNum` from **boq_table**.
- `executedQuantLastSummary` || `priceLastWorks` || `executedQuantBetw2Sum` from **summary**.
- `priceCurrentWorks` from **submittal**.

---

And there are `two` columns that should fill after the calculation process in two fields displayed in `DataGrid` view is it possible to make this calculation automatically after fill data in `dataGridView` or should it be before filling?

I am trying to use Full outer in code below but it doesn't work.

```
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT ubc.boq_table.itemNum AS '1', ubc.boq_table.descriptionOfWork AS '2', ubc.boq_table.unit AS '3', ubc.boq_table.contractualQuantity AS '4', ubc.boq_table.priceNum AS '5' , ubc.summary.executedQuantLastSummary AS '6', ubc.summary.priceLastWorks AS '7 ', ubc.summary.executedQuantBetw2Sum AS '8' , ubc.submittal.priceCurrentWorks AS '9 '  from ubc.boq_table FULL OUTER JOIN ubc.summary ON ubc.boq_table.itemNum = ubc.submittal.itemNum = ubc.summary.itemNum where projectName='" + projectNameText.Text + "' And itemNum= '" + textBox3.Text + "' ", connection);

            table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: Did you try using the query directly in MySQL before doing it in c#? Also please define "*it doesn't work*". (btw, using numbers for column names is quite odd - `AS '1'`)

Answer (score 0):

To make full outer join on 3 tables

```
SELECT t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.value = t2.value
        LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.value = t3.value
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.value = t2.value
        LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.value = t3.value
WHERE t1.value IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
FROM t3 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.value = t3.value
        LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.value = t3.value
WHERE t1.value IS NULL AND t2.value IS NULL
```

As an alternative for this:

```
SELECT t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.value = t2.value
        FULL OUTER JOIN t3 ON t1.value = t3.value
```

Reference from SO post :[Full outer MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497230/how-to-full-outer-join-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

And to load data to datatable :

```
public void LoadData()
{
    DataTable NewDataTable = new DataTable();

    string FullOuterQuery = "Your reworked query";
    MySqlDataAdapter MySQLDA= new MySqlDataAdapter(FullOuterQuery, connection);
    MySQLDA.Fill(NewDataTable);
    MySQLDA.Dispose();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = NewDataTable;
}
```

Comment: please can you explain to me why you type "IS NULL"? I need query with exactly where condition I typed

Comment: You can change that, it was copy/pasted from another post, but this is exactly what You need.